# auth not working in apache

Tags: apache-httpd, authentication

I was trying to enable authentication in `apache`. I tried the following configuration items.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/balancer-manager">
    Order deny,allow
    AuthName "Restricted area for authorised users only"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/admin.users
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

```
$ cat /etc/httpd/conf/admin.users
test:kWtP2lRnbgNaK31
```

But it is not asking for credentials. What I am missing?

PLease find log content after enabling DEBUG mode

```
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:34.663221 2019] [core:info] [pid 32043] AH00096: removed PID file /run/httpd/httpd.pid (pid=32043)
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:34.663282 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32043] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:35.725075 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 29306] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:35.738035 2019] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 29306] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:35.738064 2019] [auth_digest:debug] [pid 29306] mod_auth_digest.c(250): AH01759: done
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:35.738672 2019] [slotmem_shm:debug] [pid 29306] mod_slotmem_shm.c(448): AH02301: attach looking for /run/httpd/slotmem-shm-mod_heartmonitor.shm
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:35.738688 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 29306] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:35.741178 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 29308] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:35.741214 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 29308] proxy_util.c(1885): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:35.741261 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 29308] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 29308 for (*)
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:35.741291 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 29306] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 18 10:48:35.741310 2019] [mpm_prefork:info] [pid 29306] AH00164: Server built: Oct  3 2017 09:37:04
```

Comment: Did you reload apache?

Comment: yeah..restarted done

Comment: What version of apache? What's your DocumentRoot for the included segment. What url path are you testing with? What's the corresponding log file entry?

Comment: What happens if you use `wget -S` or `curl` to access the protected page? Do you get prompted? If not, please copy and paste the command line and its headers output (not interested in your page's content) into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have that configuration working here as:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/balancer-manager>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted area for authorised users only"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/admin.users
    Require valid-user
 </Directory>
```

Then restart Apache.

Comment: I also find that your password field in `admin.users` has a strange format. Have you created it with `htpasswd` or you just edited a fake one for the question?

Comment: It is a fake one...  I tried as per your suggestion...but still no luck

Comment: Strange, working here as it is, it was literaly a cut and paste just changed for your directories. Dont you have any error logs?

Comment: Added log file content with version

Answer (score 0):

Working for me when I changed `Directory` directive with `Location` directive . Following is the snippet

```
  <Location "/balancer-manager">
   AuthName "Restricted area for authorised users only"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/admin.users
   Require valid-user
  </Location>
```

Comment: That suggests the contents `/balancer-manager` URI is provided in some other way than from files in the filesystem. Perhaps that URI is passed to another service, either using Apache proxy functionality or something like a J2EE connector module? In that case, the actual request does not get mapped to the filesystem at all, so the `<Directory>` block does not apply.